# To find the angle a particle makes with the horizontal at any time 't'

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, projectile-motion

Should you vector sum the position vectors at this time 't' or vector sum the velocity vector at this time 't' to find the angle a particle makes with the horizontal at any time 't'

Comment: There is only one position vector and only one velocity vector, so I'm not sure what you might be summing. "The angle a particle makes with the horizontal" is referring to the velocity vector.

Comment: If you means the polar angle then it is $tan^{-1}(f(x))+c$ or another expression.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to speak of the angle that a *particle* makes with a horizontal, since a point and a line together does not specify an angle.

Let $P(t)$ be the particle's position at time $t.$

Then, *with respect to the origin $O$*, **the (acute) angle made at time $t$ by the particle with the horizontal** is the acute angle between $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and the position vector $\vec{OP}.$ (Since the acute angle is desired, when using dot product, remember to take its absolute value.)

On the other hand, **the particle's direction of motion at time $t$** can be specified by the angle—not necessarily acute—between $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and its velocity vector at time $t.$

If working in $\mathbb R^2$ instead of $\mathbb R^3,$ replace $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}.$